# When I change my CSS and refresh the page, the changes aren't reflected in Safari or Chrome

Tags: safari, google-chrome, css

I set the background to red instead of the color it normally was. Didn't change. Removed the properties all together, refreshed, the texture was still there, even though I removed the line.

OS X 10.7.5

Is there a caching issue? It happens in both Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the CSS is cached.

Try holding down the "Shift" key while clicking on the refresh icon. This will usually trigger a refresh that will reload the CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: Yes - or your can use the [Web Inspector](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html) to disable cache while the inspector is open.

Comment: Note: In Chrome, you can not prevent caching unless the dev tools are open. As soon as you close them, Chrome caches, whatever your settings. If your using a server, you can serve the file via a handler, then add a timestamp to the request that the handler just ignores. Because the timestamp is always different, so the URL changes, Chrome can't safely cache the response, so it always requests a fresh copy.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a browser caching issue and remedied as Dave suggested, however if that didn't work, it may also be that your hosting provider has a caching solution turned on for your server.  If clearing your browser's cache on Safari or Chrome, as Dave suggested, does not work for some reason, try calling your hosting provider or checking your cPanel to clear your servers cache.  Are you using Wordpress or another CMS?  If you have a caching plugin activated, check the cache settings on that plugin as well. And clear the cache on the plugin while your there.

Hopefully I could be of some help.  Ping me if you have any other questions.